# Not to sweep floor on day of traveling (source)

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, travel, cleaning, hasidic-story

I just heard in the name of  Rabbi Moncowits in Montreal that on day of traveling it is forbidden to sweep the floor.

Because he once was in an accident and the Lubavicher Rebbe told him it was because one of the boys in the car had swept the floor on that day.

And then Rabbi Moncowits researched it and found a source for this.

What is the source?

Comment: I heard a similar story about sitting down before a trip (with rabbi kominettski) (it happens that not religious russians (russian jews) also have this minhag but do not have a conection with judaism)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a general superstition:

See [here](https://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-ideas/weird-and-wacky/the-most-bizarre-travel-superstitions-around-the-world/news-story/efab11d306dc556d9894f1c6e6192cf1):

> **Bulgaria: Skip sweeping after someone departs**
>
> No matter how untidy your abode gets after you leave for a trip, make
>   sure no one sweeps up after you.
>
> As the legend goes in Bulgaria, using a broom or vacuum to clean up is
>   considered a symbol of sweeping that person away, hindering a safe
>   return.
>
> Consider this another excuse to avoid cleaning.

And [here](https://www.express.co.uk/travel/articles/634254/Travel-superstitions-around-the-world-pictures):

> Whilst many of us have a quick vacuum around the house before we leave
>   for our holiday, in Bulgaria, this is considered bad luck.
>
> It’s believed that sweeping is a symbol of sweeping that person away
>   and prevents a safe return.

And [here](https://www.visitiom.co.uk/blog/travel-superstitions/):

> **Bulgaria Clean Sweep**
>
> Make sure nobody sweeps your house soon after you have left! It is
>   believed that doing this is similar to sweeping that person away and
>   prevents their safe return.

And [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Aft4c9GauRsC&pg=PA894&lpg=PA894&dq=superstition%20sweeping%20before%20traveling&source=bl&ots=iBYh0NZ_Js&sig=TmDcVburuS0-4ouaTv5NhDoI2Cc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPt7fjoZDcAhUDmeAKHRj-Bzs4FBDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=superstition%20sweeping%20before%20traveling&f=false):

> If you sweep the home on the first day that the head of the house
>   starts on a journey, he will never return. (Persia)

And [here](https://www.skyscanner.com.ph/news/top-7-weird-travel-superstitions):

> In Bulgaria, it is believed that when a house is swept just after a
>   person leaves, it prevents that person’s safe return!

Comment: Yes i heard it it russian but afterbhearing the OP it seems to me posible that it is a jewish thing (maybe kabolistic) other learnd about

Comment: @hazoriz Alternatively, the superstition infiltrated some Jewish communities.

Comment: i hope that is not the case